# Object of class Conn could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

El siguiente error se me presenta a la hora de diseñar las consultas a la base de datos, adjunto el código fuente:

Validaciones.php:

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
header('Location: vistas/home.php');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $usuario = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['contrasena'];

require 'config/conn.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE username = :username AND password = :contrasena";
$consulta = $conexion-> prepare($sql);
$consulta = execute(array('usuario' => $usuario, 'contrasena' => $password));

$resultado = $consulta ->fetch();

if($resultado !== false){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: vistas/home.php');
}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
}
?>
```

Cógido de la conexión:

```
<?php

class Conn
{

//Atributos de la base de datos
private $dbname;
private $host;
private $user;
private $pass;
private $port;
private $conexion;

//Métodos
public function __construct()
{
    $this->dbname = "scrum";
    $this->host = "localhost";
    $this->user = "postgres";
    $this->pass = "1234";
    $this->port = "5432";

    try{
        $this->conexion = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->host.
                            ";port=".$this->port.
                            ";dbname=".$this->dbname.
                            ";user=".$this->user.
                            ";password=".$this->pass);
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Tienes el siguiente error:", $e->getMessage();
        }
}



}

?>
```

Comment: seguro que esto es correcto `echo "Tienes el siguiente error:", $e->getMessage();` ? no deberías usar el punto `.` para concatenar tanto la cadena como el mensaje de error? o simplemente mosrtrar `$e->getMessage();`

Comment: Si, es un error que no había notado y gracias. Y lo referente al enunciado, ¿no sabes que es?

Comment: Después de esta línea: `require 'config/conn.php';`, deberías crear una instancia de la conexión y asignarla a la variable, algo así: **`$conexion=new Conn();`** Hasta el momento no dispones de una instancia real de la conexión porque no has invocado el constructor de la clase. Si así no funciona, entonces debes agregar un `getter` a la clase que te devuelva la conexión.

Comment: Lo hice, pero ahora me arroja el siguiente error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conn::prepare() in C:\wamp64\www\login\validaciones.php on line 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comprendo que quieres hacer de tu clase `Conn` un envoltorio (wrapper) de tu clase PDO, lo cual me parece perfecto, porque de ese modo cada vez que necesites conectar no tienes que estar pasando las credenciales. Además, si conectas donde quiera que uses la base de datos y se ofrece tener que cambiar la contraseña por ejemplo, no tendrás que empezar a buscar en el código donde quiera que conectaste para hacerlo, sino que lo cambias en tu envoltorio nada más.

El problema es que para que la clase tenga todas las funcionalidades de PDO es necesario hacer que la misma extienda de PDO. Esto se hará simplemente escribiendo  la clase así:

```
class Conn extends PDO {
```

Haciendo eso, ya tu clase dispondrá de todos los métodos de PDO.

Pero, la clase necesita unas pequeñas mejoras:

- debes llamar al constructor de la clase padre, que es PDO
- vamos también a establecer algunas configuraciones importantes que te ahorrarán futuros dolores de cabeza: establecer una codificación adecuada, apagar las preparaciones emuladas y establecer correctamente el manejo de excepciones

La clase quedaría entonces así:

```
<?php
class Conn extends PDO
{

    //Atributos de la base de datos
    private $dbname;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $port;

    //Métodos
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbname = "scrum";
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->user = "postgres";
        $this->pass = "1234";
        $this->port = "5432";
        $charset="utf8";
        $dsn="pgsql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname;charset=$charset";
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try{
            parent::__construct($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Tienes el siguiente error:", $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Ahora para usarla, sólo tienes que incluir el archivo y crear una nueva instancia de `Conn`:

```
require 'config/conn.php';
$conexion=new Conn();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE username = :username AND password = :contrasena";
$consulta = $conexion-> prepare($sql);
$consulta = execute(array(':username' => $usuario, ':contrasena' => $password));
//Reste del código
```

Dado que `Conn` extiende de `PDO`, tendrás ahora disponible en `$conexion` todos los métodos de la clase `PDO`.

Espero te sea de utilidad. Si algo no funciona o te quedan dudas, lo puedes expresar en comentarios.

**Nota:** El array del `execute` era erróneo, lo he corregido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, aunque me queda una duda, en el try catch estamos tomando elementos de la clase PDO para generar la conexión no ?

Comment: De nada @CristianCamiloCadavidEscarr Es así como dices,  en el `try` invocamos al constructor de la clase padre (`parent`), que es la clase PDO en sí misma. De ese modo tu clase puede usar cualquiera de los métodos de la clase PDO (más otros métodos personalizados que quisieras crear en el futuro), y además te crea una sola instancia de PDO.

Comment: Enserio muchas gracias, como aprendiz de este mundo de la programación es muy útil para mí este tipo de ayudas y comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Yo veo que tienes dos problemas.

Primero, estás asumiendo que al incluir la clase Conn se genera mágicamente un objeto `$conn` que es una instancia de PDO. En realidad lo único que ocurre es que puedes hacer algo con la clase Conn.

Supongamos que haces entonces:

```
$conexion = new Conn();
```

Ahora conexión es una instancia de la clase Conn, por lo que ya puedes ocupar sus métodos de instancia.

Ahora viene el segundo problema. Aunque implementes lo anterior, `$conexion` no tiene tal cosa como un método `prepare`. En realidad tendrías que hacerlo con algo como:

```
require 'config/conn.php';
$conexion = new Conn();
$sql = "SELECT ... ";

$consulta = $conexion->conexion->prepare($sql);
```

Porque es la propiedad de instancia `conexion` la que constituye una instancia de PDO, y no la instancia misma de Conn.

---

Una manera de ahorrar esta sintaxis (conexion->conexion) es la que indica A. Cedano. Otra manera común es usar un getter que encapsule el uso de la variable de instancia *(**EDIT**: había puesto public class en vez de public function a los métodos. Una vergüenza. Gracias [Cristian Camilo Cadavid Escarr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/106981/cristian-camilo-cadavid-escarr) por avisarme)*

```
class Conn {

  protected $conexion;

  public function __construct() {
       $this->conexion = new PDO(...);
  }

  public function getConexion() {
       return $this->conexion;
  }

}
```

Y entonces instanciarla y usar el getter para encapsular la propiedad:

```
require 'config/conn.php';
$conn = new Conn();
$conexion = $conn->getConexion();
$sql = "SELECT ... ";

$consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
```

De esta manera tu propiedad `$conexion` puede ser de tipo protected, cosa que nadie la use directamente, sino que deba llamarla con el getter. Con ese encapsulamiento la declaración de la clase y su posterior uso quedan desacoplados y el día de mañana eres libre de rebautizar `$conexion` como  `$misuperconexionqueyosolamentesecomosellama` y daría igual, el usuario no la usa directamente sino mediante el getter..

---

Hay otras maneras de implementar lo mismo. Si quieres ahorrarte el paso de instanciar la clase, puedes hacer que la instancia de por sí sea una propiedad estática de la clase, y por lo tanto pueda accederse desde un método estático. Si no existe la instancia, la crea. Luego te devuelve la propiedad `$conexion`.

```
class Conn {

   protected $conexion;
   protected static $instance;

   public class __construct() {
       $this->conexion = new PDO(...);
   }

   public static function getConexion() {
       if(!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new static();
       }
       return self::$instance->conexion;
   }
}
```

De manera que podrías hacer:

```
require 'config/conn.php';
$conexion = Conn::getConexion();

$sql = "SELECT ... ";
$consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
```

Este último ejemplo está usando el patrón Singleton que, a estas alturas, no tiene muchos admiradores que digamos.

Volviendo al primer problema, **claramente hay una parte del código que no nos estás mostrando**. Nada del código que pegaste (y a partir del cual te hemos respondido) generaría ese error.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, ¿ por qué añades una public class al interior de la clase Conn ?, no debería ser una función ?

Comment: chuuuuta que vergüenza, eran public functions :(

Comment: Nada de vergüenza, antes muchísimas gracias por tus aportes