# Como crear conexión pdo segura

Tags: php

tengo esta clase con una función de pdo pero no sé si está correcto, funciona pero no sé si es segura.

```
/* Class Database */
class Database{
    /* Function connect */
    public static function connect(){
        try{
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cursophp","root","");
            return $db;
            $db = null;
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e){
            print "¡Error al establecer una conexión con la base de datos!";
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya que estas dentro del ámbito de una clase, por que no declarar a `$db` como **static** y **protected ** para que de este modo no tengas que hacer una instancia cuando la ocupes y usar **protected** que indica que solo podrá ser accedida por la clase donde exista y aquella que la herede; descartando a las demás

Comment: por otro lado si ya estas controlando el comportamiento esperado y el error a través de un `try catch` considero que usar `die()` para matar la ejecución del script esta de más

Comment: Podrías por favor darme un ejemplo práctico por favor?

Comment: die() lo cogí de php.net, de algo como para no dejar conexiones abiertas o algo así.

Comment: El problema con tu clase es que no podrás aprovecharla para usar los métodos de PDO como `prepare, fetch` etc.  Lo mejor sería hacer que extienda de PDO y evitar el uso de `new`, pasando las credenciales al constructor del padre (que no es otro que PDO). Entonces sí estaríamos hablando de un envoltorio real de PDO. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo básico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217012/29967), el cual incluye dos configuraciones importantes a no obviar: apagar las preparaciones emuladas y setear bien el manejo de excepciones. Otra cosa, usa contraseñas largas. Si quieres te digo por qué.

Comment: Si claro dime todo

Comment: Muy simple, y por eso insisto en establecer correctamente el manejo de excepciones con `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Cuando no se manejan correctamente las excepciones y hay algún fallo tratando de construir una instancia de PDO, en el log de errores se escribe el mensaje de error, incluyendo allí también las credenciales de conexión: usuario, contraseña, etc. Como entenderás, los log de errores son de los archivos favoritos de los hackers, y si tienes la clave de la BD en tu log de errores y un hacker da con ella, pobre de ti.

Comment: Muchas gracias por esta información, voy a trabajar en ello, agradezco mucho su tiempo.

Comment: @Shoropio sería genial si le das un mas uno a quien te respondió en la publicación que te recomienda; pues es una guía muy completa de todas las observaciones que te hizo

Comment: Un problema de seguridad que podrías considerar es que tienes las credenciales directamente en el código. Si por cualquier motivo el servidor muestra tu código en lugar de ejecutarlo (como comenta otro usuario en una pregunta realizada hace un rato) u ocurre un error de conexión y se muestra el error de PHP (que puede incluir un pequeño snippet de la parte donde ocurrió el error) tus credenciales quedarán expuestas.

Comment: Dime más @Alvaro? Cómo puedo resolverlo?. @shadow vieras que no sé a qué se refiere con dar "un más"?

Comment: @Shoropio puedes tener las credenciales fuera de la raíz del servidor y leerlas desde PHP (en tu fichero de conexión u otro anterior). De ese modo las credenciales no estarán en el código en sí evitando posibles problemas de seguridad (los desarrolladores no tienen por qué saber cuáles son los credenciales y tampoco el sistema de control de versiones, y evitas que estén disponibles en caso de error o si otros sistemas de seguridad fallan).

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias limitaciones en tu clase, muchas de ellas han sido ya señaladas en varios comentarios míos y de otros usuarios.

En este código voy a implementar casi todo lo que ha surgido en los comentarios:

- Poner opciones adecuadas en la conexión: manejo de errores, apagar preparaciones emuladas, setear un juego de caracteres uniforme (`utf-8`)
- Extender la clase de PDO, de lo contrario no podrás aprovechar con esta conexión de todos los métodos de que dispone PDO
- Evitar `new`, pasando las credenciales al constructor del padre
- Asegurar las credenciales, usando en este caso un archivo aparte. Ese archivo puede estar en una carpeta reservada, incluso oculta, a la que sólo ciertos usuarios tengan acceso

Considera también la recomendación de usar contraseñas largas. Aunque si las excepciones se manejan bien no hay riesgo de que la contraseña se escriba en el log de errores, si usas una contraseña larga (30 o más caracteres), ésta, de mostrarse en el log de errores se mostraría truncada, no completa :-)

Vamos con el código que propongo:

### Ocultar las credenciales en un archivo

Puedes crear un archivo en cualquier carpeta, preferiblemente una carpeta oculta, fuera de `public_html`, de forma que no se tenga acceso a ella por URL.

Vamos a suponer que ese archivo está en la carpeta  `.credentials`, dentro del directorio `home` y que se llama `db.php.ini`, su contenido es este:

```
<?php return; ?>
; credenciales
host=localhost
user=tuUsuario
pass="UqMsN[)VPn&gunmv3KzE?3Q&QwD48E/xs>+xscpUrKCvV.8C/Z"
dbname=tuBaseDeDatos
```

La 1ª línea está puesta por si alguien logra acceder por URL al archivo (cosa poco probable si lo pones fuera de un directorio accesible), no muestra nada de lo que hay en él.

Luego tendremos los valores asociados por cada clave: `host, user, pass, dbname`. Los valores pueden ir sin comillas. En el caso de `pass` lo he puesto entre comillas porque si la clave tiene caracteres especiales problemáticos o comillas simples, puede haber una interpretación errónea de su valor y fallar la conexión al momento de obtenerla. He puesto un ejemplo de clave larga. Debes cambiarla por tu propia clave. Por favor no uses claves como `micuchichi72`. Hoy día hay programas muy potentes capaces de adivinar tu cuchicuchi y el año en que naciste :-)

---

#### Crear un envoltorio de la conexión PDO

Ahora vamos a crear un envoltorio (wrapper) de la clase PDO, aplicando lo que ya se ha dicho en comentarios. Y mostrando cómo leer las credenciales usando el archivo `db.php.ini` de más arriba.

```
<?php
class Database extends PDO
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        /* Aquí hay que usar la ruta donde se encuentre el archivo con las credenciales*/
        $iniData = parse_ini_file("//home/.credentials/db.php.ini");
        $host=$iniData["host"];
        $dbname=$iniData["dbname"];
        $user=$iniData["user"];
        $pass=$iniData["pass"];
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";

    /**
     *  El array $options es muy importante para tener un PDO bien configurado
     *  
     *  1. PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT: sirve para usar conexiones persistentes
     *      se puede establecer a true si se quiere usar este tipo de conexión.
     *      Ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967 
     *      En la práctica, el uso de conexiones persistentes ha dado algunos problemas
     *  2. PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES: Se usa para desactivar emulación de consultas preparadas 
     *      forzando el uso real de consultas preparadas. 
     *      Es muy importante establecerlo a false para prevenir Inyección SQL. 
     *      Ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967
     *  3. PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION También muy importante para un correcto manejo de las excepciones. 
     *      Si no se usa bien, cuando hay algún error este se podría escribir en el log revelando datos como la contraseña !!!
     *  4. PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'": establece el juego de caracteres a utf8, 
     *      evitando caracteres extraños en pantalla. 
     *      Ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967
     *      Esto se puede hacer también agregando esto a $dsn: charset=utf8 ... 
     */

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE, 
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
        );

        try {
                /* 
                    *Intentar la conexión llamando al constructor del padre que no es otro que PDO
                */
                parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            /* Escribir posibles excepciones en el error_log o en pantalla */
            error_log($this->error = $e->getMessage(),0);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

#### Modo de uso

```
/* 
   *Si no usas Autoloader, debes antes incluir el archivo
   *En el include hay que poner la ruta y nombre de archivo correctos, claro está
*/
include_once('Database.php');
$db=new Database();
```

Et voilà, tendrás en el objeto `$db` una conexión a PDO con todas las de la ley, podrás usar cualquiera de sus métodos.

Comment: Definitivamente voy a usar esto, Pura vida desde Costa Rica.

Comment: @Shoropio Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.