# Conexión PDO Orientada a objetos

Tags: php

Muy buenas tardes caballeros, mi siguiente inquietud es como puedo hacer para que mi conexión orientada a objetos se pueda instanciar en un modelo y se pueda acceder a ella como si fuera un método, lo que sucede esque al intentar realizar una función y acceder a ella para hacer una consulta me dice que no se encuentra dicho método pero esta misma es un objeto __construct de mi conexion por ende debe arrojarme la conexión pero me lanza los datos en object o en su defecto objetos.

```
namespace models;
use PDO;
class Conexion{
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $dbname = "veterinaria";
private $charset = "utf8";
private $port = 3306;
private $conexion = null;

public function __construct()
{   
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->dbname};charset={$this->charset};port={$this->port}";
        $this->conexion = new \PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, array(
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE
    ));
    } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
        print $ex->getMessage();
        print $ex->getCode();
        print_r($ex->getTrace());
        print $ex->getLine();   
    }
public function get()
{
    return $this->conexion;
} 
}
```

Este es el ejemplo de mi conexión

```
namespace models;
use PDO;
require('Conexion.php');
class Paciente{
private $id_paciente;
private $fk_tipo;
private $nombre;
private $edad;
private $foto;
private $c_vacunacion;
private $fk_dueño;
private $peso;
private $conexion;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->conexion = new Conexion();
}
```

De esto hablo aqui instancia esa conexion en otro constructor de otra clase y se lo asigno a un atributo llamado conexion;

```
public function retornarPaciente(int $id_paciente):array
{
    $sql = "SELECT id_paciente, nombre, edad, foto, peso FROM paciente WHERE id_paciente = :id";
    $stmn = $this->conexion->get()->prepare($sql);
    $stmn->bindParam(":id", $id_paciente, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmn->execute();
    return $stmn->fetch();
}
```

Como hago para que en vez de llamar  a una funcion dentro de mi conexion que retorne esta misma pueda acceder de esta forma directa 
$this->conexion->prepare($sql);

en vez de hacer esto de llamar a la funcion get():
$this->conexion->get()->prepare($sql);

Comment: Tu clase va a tener un problema y es que no vas a poder beneficiarte de todos los métodos de la clase `PDO` porque la misma no extiende de PDO. Si revisas [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217012/29967) podrás ver un ejemplo de cómo crear la clase. Al extender de PDO podrás usar cualquier método suyo.

Comment: Caballero muchísimas gracias por tu excelente aporte ahora tengo mas uso de mis propiedades de mi conexión y puedo utilizar todos los métodos de mi instancia, gran aporte ¡Crack!