# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO_7::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Buen día a todos. Estoy iniciándome en la **programación orientada a objetos con PHP**, ya hice mi conexión, pero al instanciar el objeto me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO_7::prepare()
```

Esta es mi clase para hacer la conexion a la BD:

```
<?php 
class PDO_7 {
  private $pdo;
  private $credenciales;
  private $isConnected = false;
  private $parametros;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->Connect();
    $this->parametros = array();
  }

  private function Connect()
{
    //lee credenciales desde el archivo ini
    $this->credenciales = parse_ini_file("../credentials/bd.php.ini");
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->credenciales["dbnombre"] . ';host=' . $this->credenciales["host"] . '';
    $pwd = $this->credenciales["clave"];
    $usr = $this->credenciales["usuario"];


    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        pdo::ATTR_ERRMODE => pdo::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
    );

    try {
        #intentar la conexion
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $options);

        #conexion exitosa, asignar true a la variable booleana isConnected
        $this->isConnected = true;
        echo 'Exitoso';
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log($this->error = $e->getMessage(), 0);
    }
  }


}?>
```

Mi otro archivo se llama conectate_2.php, en realidad lo que estoy haciendo es hacer pruebas de si se hacen las consultas, pero me aparece el error, el código del archivo antes mencionado es:

```
<?php
require_once 'PDO_7.php';

$conexion = new PDO_7();
$st = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario');
$st->execute();?>
```

No soy experto en php, soy nivel inicial, si me pudieran decir en dónde estoy haciendo mal se los agradecería.
P.D. El código lo encontré en github, ya verifiqué la documentación, pero no encuentro más información para resolver este error.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `prepare` es un método de la clase PDO, pero no te lo reconoce porque tu clase `PDO_7` no extiende de PDO. Tienes que hacerla extender de PDO y crear la instancia llamando a `parent`, sólo así podrás usar los métodos como `prepare, query, execute, fetch`, etc.

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217012/29967) puede ayudarte a entender cómo escribir el código de tu clase para que te permita usar todos los métodos propios de la clase PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo dice claramente, que no tiene el metodo prepare definido. Si te fijas bien, veras que solo tiene definido 1 metodo llamado `Connect()` y es privado.

El metodo `prepare` se encuentra en la instancia de la variable `$dpo`, por lo que si defines un metodo que retorne esa instancias, podras acceder al metodo `prepare`.

```
class PDO_7 {
  private $pdo;
  private $credenciales;
  private $isConnected = false;
  private $parametros;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->Connect();
    $this->parametros = array();
  }

  // agregas este metodo a la clase
  public function getPDO(sql){
     return $this->$pdo;
  }
  //..

}
```

Entonces para ejecutarlo:

```
  <?php
require_once 'PDO_7.php';

$conexion = new PDO_7();
$st = $conexion->getPDO()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario');
$st->execute();?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí funciona.