# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function prepare()

Tags: php, pdo

Deseo hacer una simple consulta que me traiga datos de un tabla. Tengo el error del titulo en el archivo donde preparo y ejecuto la consulta.

El error exacto es:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function prepare() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\pos_venta\Config\App\Query.php:47 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\pos_venta\Models\UsuariosModel.php(39):
> Query->select('SELECT * FROM u...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\pos_venta\Controllers\Usuarios.php(16):
> UsuariosModel->getUsuario() #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\pos_venta\index.php(79): Usuarios->index('') #3 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pos_venta\Config\App\Query.php on line 47

```
<?php


    class Query extends Conexion{

        private $pdo, $con, $sql;

        public function __construct()
        {

            $this->pdo = new Conexion();

            $this->con = $this->pdo->conect();

        }

        public function select(string $sql)
        {
            $this->sql = $sql;

            $result = $this->con-prepare($this->sql); //linea del error

            $result->execute();

            $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $data;


        }

    }


?>
```

Comment: Si marca el método *`prepare`* como indefinido es por que probablemente tienes algún detalle en la clase donde estableces la conexión

Comment: ¿Tu clase `Conexion` extiende de PDO? `prepare` es un métod de la clase PDO y para poder usarlo en clases envoltorio tendrías que hacer que esas clases extiendan de PDO. [He aquí un ejemplo de clase envoltorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217012/29967).