# Problema al insertar llave foránea en tabla relacionada PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo algunos problemas en la realización de esta actividad.
Quiero obtener el ultimo id generado en la tabla **Cliente** para después insertarlo en la tabla **Cliente_correo** ya que estas tienen una relación. Este código esta hecho por funciones PDO pero al momento de ejecutar el programa me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method conexion::lastInsertId() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prueba1/login_registrar.php:105 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prueba1/login_registrar.php on line 105

Las tablas tienen los siguientes atributos:

**Cliente**

1. id_cliente
2. Razon_social
3. Sociedad_mercantil
4. Capital_vairable
5. nombre_empresa

**Cliente_correo**

1. id_cliente(fk)
2. correo_responsable

Este es mi código donde recibo los registros por medio de un formulario y los inserto por medio de PDO:

```
<?php

   ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); 
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

  include_once("conexion.php");

   /* Recibimos los registros ingresados en el formulario*/
       $Razon_social = $_POST["Razon_social"];
       $Sociedad_mercantil = $_POST["Sociedad_mercantil"];
       $Capital_variable = $_POST["Capital_variable"];
       $Nombre_empresa = $_POST["Nombre_empresa"];
       $correo_responsable = $_POST["correo_responsable"];

        if(isset($_POST["enviar"]))
          {

        $db = new conexion(); //Llamamos al constructor de la conexion
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Cliente(
         Razon_social, 
         Sociedad_mercantil, 
         Capital_variable, 
         Nombre_empresa
           )VALUES(
          :Razon_social, 
          :Sociedad_mercantil, 
          :Capital_variable, 
          :Nombre_empresa
           )";


           $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($sql);
           $stmt ->bindParam(":Razon_social",$Razon_social);
           $stmt ->bindParam(":Sociedad_mercantil",$Sociedad_mercantil);
           $stmt ->bindParam(":Capital_variable",$Capital_variable);
           $stmt ->bindParam(":Nombre_empresa",$Nombre_empresa);

           $Id_cliente = $db->lastInsertId();

           $sql = "INSERT INTO Cliente_correo(
            id_cliente_correo,
            correo_responsable
            )values(
            :Id_cliente,
            :correo_responsable
             )";

             $stmt ->bindParam(":Id_cliente",$Id_cliente);
             $stmt ->bindParam(":correo_responsable",$correo_responsable);


              if($stmt->execute()){

              header("location: index.html");
              }else print("Error en la consulta");

              }else{
              print("Dede completar todos los campo del formulario");
                  }

                ?>
```

Mi código de conexión:

```
class conexion {

private $host;
private $db;
private $user;
private $password;
private $charset;

public function __construct(){
    $this->host = 'localhost';
    $this->db = 'prueba';
    $this->user = 'root';
    $this->password = '';
    $this->charset = 'utf8mb4';
}

function connect(){
    try{
        $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];

        $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);

        return $pdo;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
}

 ?>
```

Espero y puedan ayudarme a solucionar este problema. Gracias

Comment: Por favor, agrega el error entero, no lo cortes. El error dice que tu método, no está definido.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method conexion::lastInsertId() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prueba1/login_registrar.php:105 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prueba1/login_registrar.php on line 105

Comment: El problema es que tu clase `conexion` no extiende de PDO, por tanto, no podrás usar el método `lastInsertId()` desde la instancia de la misma creada con el constructor. Puedes hacer dos cosas: 1. Intentar obtener la conexión llamando a `connect()`; 2. O bien hacer que tu clase extienda de PDO, en cuyo caso podrás usar cualquier método de PDO desde una instancia de `conexion` creada con el constructor. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217012/29967) de una clase envoltorio que extiende de PDO.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu clase `conexion` no extiende de PDO, por tanto, no podrás usar el método `lastInsertId()` desde la instancia de la misma creada con el constructor (tu actual constructor no te crea aún un objeto PDO).

Puedes hacer dos cosas:

1. Intentar obtener la conexión llamando a `connect()` (no estoy seguro de que funcione, no lo he probado);

   En ese caso tendrías que cambiar esto:

   ```
   $db = new conexion(); //Llamamos al constructor de la conexion
   ```

   Por esto:

   ```
   $mConexion = new conexion(); 
   $db=$mConexion->connect();
   ```

   Aquí, en teoría, `$db` sí sería una instancia de PDO, retornada desde la clase `conexion`, desde el método `connect()`, según lo tienes definido.

   PERO, quedaría otro cambio: **NO invoques más a `connect()` en este contexto**, pues estarías conectado constantemente, lo cual no es una buena idea. Entonces cambia esto:

   ```
      $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($sql);
   ```

   Por esto:

   ```
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   ```

   Y así con todo lo que deba usar a``$db`.

---

2. O bien puedes hacer que tu clase extienda de PDO, en cuyo caso podrás usar cualquier método de PDO desde una instancia de `conexion` creada con el constructor. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217012/29967) de una clase envoltorio que extiende de PDO.

   Si implementas una clase envoltorio de este modo, el código quedaría así:

   ```
   $db = new conexion();

   #Y para todos los usos que requieran de la BD
   $stmt=$db->prepare();
   $db->lastInsertId(); //... etc
   ```

Comment: Hola decidí optar que la clase extienda a PDO y algunas líneas de código quedarían así `class conexión extends PDO`, en el registro: `$db = new conexión();`  `$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);`   `$Id_cliente = $db->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Pero ahora el código modificado, al ejecutarlo, me sale una advertencia y un error diferente al anterior y son los siguientes: **Warning: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prueba1/login_registrar.php on line 82**   y el error:    **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prueba1/login_registrar.php:83 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prueba1/login_registrar.php on line 83**